# Sharepoint 2010 InfoPath form to wsp

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am assigned a task to customize edit/new form of a list(Calendar list) by InfoPath 2010, then package these forms to a feature that can be deployed to many site.

I found a small number of article mention this case and nothing can help me, so are there anyone can help me?

Thanks